# Are 4N35 optocouplers clamped at 22V?

Tags: current, resistors, mains, opto-isolator, sensing

I am trying to detect mains with an ESP32, for that I started testing this circuit:

[image]

I bought a [4N35](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81181/4n35.pdf) optocoupler and 110kΩ resistors.

My first test was using 2 resistors in series, so R1 = 220kΩ.

The LED turns on, I see 22V and 0.96mA across pins 1 and 2.

My math:

`V = I * R => 230V = 0.001A * 230KΩ`

Then I added 10 series resistors, so R1 = 1.1MΩ.

The LED also works, I still see 22V across pin 1 and 2 of the optocupler, and I = 0.21mA.

My math:

`V = I * R => 230V = 0.00021A * 1095KΩ`

Why is the voltage of the optocoupler *clamped* at 22V?

How can I calculate the optimal (maximum?) R1 value that will make my circuit work?

Comment: If you're seeing more than about 1.5 volts on the input, either your optocoupler is dead or you're measuring things wrong.

Comment: Are you measuring with an oscilloscope or multimeter? If you are measuring with a multimeter, you might see when it starts to break down with reverse voltage and clamping to some -30 V or similar, half of the time. You are most probably damaging your optocoupler with that 325 V reverse voltage. Add a diode in series!

Comment: @winny I believe an antiparallel diode is more usual for optocouplers, but either would work.

Comment: Thanks @winny. I have added a diode and now it is under 2V :S ... still surprised that it works with 1.1MΩ. consumption is very little compared to `HCPL3700`

Comment: @Hearth That's a safer but more wasteful option. I was thinking about how the two diodes in series would share voltage. Probably not ideal.

Comment: @winny That was my thought; considering that the reverse voltage rating of opto inputs is usually 5 volts, clamping it with an antiparallel diode is probably the better option.

Comment: Very little light is needed to turn "on" the photo-transistor.

Comment: You MUST use an antiparallel diode to clamp your opto LED input. If you're veeerrrrry lucky, then the high R1 has limited breakdown current to something that hasn't blown the diode. Why is it clamped at 22 V? That's the reverse breakdown voltage.

Comment: Thanks all! I have learned a lot from your comments. If anybody wants to write the same comment as answer, I will mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I did not have a diode, the optocoupler could not handle the 325V reverse voltage.

I was measuring 22V because that is the reverse breakdown voltage of the diode.

By adding a diode in series to R1, I started measuring 1.2V as expected.

Since this was just a test, I did not try the anti-parallel solution, but it is probably a better solution, and the explanation is in the comments to the question.

I did no try further because I will probably use a bidirectional input optocoupler, which solves this problem as well.